# KeyError: 'date' while set date column as an index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, datetime-format

[file.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLPC5.png)
have a CSV file with 'date' column and want to set its values as index but got an error KeyError: 'date'

tried:

```
file=pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep='delimiter' , encoding='latin-1')
file=file.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(file['date'].values))
```

date column looks like this :

```
05/02/2017
06/02/2017
07/02/2017
```

Comment: `sep='delimiter'` this itself looks wrong to me. Should have been similar to `sep=','`. Also, does your csv file have the first row of coiumn names? If so, you should also include `header=True` as another attribute in the pd.read_csv call. Could you post an image of how the first few rows and columns of your original csv file looks like?

Comment: thx.but when  using  sep=',' got another error 'ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 2'  and  header=True doesn't recognzied and needs integer value so i passed header=1 as the first row

Comment: Just post an image of the first 5 rows and columns of the data.csv and things would be clear

Comment: have you tried passing  index_col = "date" in the read_csv function?